# stripe api: multiple plans / subscriptions, single invoice

Tags: stripe-payments

I've been reading through the docs all day and am having a hard time understanding if this is possible.

What I want is to subscribe a user to multiple plans and have it charged on a single invoice, with recurring payments monthly from when the invoice was originally billed.

In the docs it says:

> "Note that multiple subscriptions on a customer results in a separate billing cycle, invoice, and charge for each subscription, even if the plans have the same billing interval and the subscriptions are created at the same time."

Which is not promising

But then the api explicitly allows for creating invoices with multiple items through the InvoiceItems api. It seems this is mostly for custom/unique actions on the customer, like applying discounts or one off charges outside of the regular subscription cycle.

I suppose I could manually keep track of billing cycles and manually create multi-item invoices, but I would much rather have this automated through Stripe.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are describing is now supported in the Stripe API: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/multiplan. The idea is to add multiple plans to a subscription, a restriction being that all plans must share the same interval.

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
var stripe = require("stripe")("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer: "cus_91elFtZU3tt11g",
  items: [
    {
      plan: "basic-monthly",
    },
    {
      plan: "additional-license",
      quantity: 2,
    },
  ]
}, function(err, subscription) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

Comment: Adding the multiplan under single subscription is not doable when we have different proration date for different subscription.

Comment: Also keep in mind other restrictions, e.g. single currency (issue for my use case) or 20 products/subscription max - https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/multiple-products#restrictions

Answer (score 8):

## 2024 latest recommendations

Now, the recommended workflow to handle that scenario is:

- create `product` and `prices` instead of `plans`
- create a `subscription` (with a `price`)
- add as much `subscriptionItem` as needed to that `subscription`

Your customer can have has much `subscriptionItems` as needed. He will be billed once on the `subscription` recurring basis, and have only one invoice. It also handle if you add the `subscriptionItem` in the middle of a month.

[stripe doc: Subscriptions with multiple products](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/multiple-products)
[Stripe API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_items)

```js
// add item to existing subscription
await stripe.subscriptionItems.create({
    subscription: subscriptionId,
    price: priceId,
    quantity,
});
```

Comment: The quantity has a sad limit of 20 :-/

Comment: @OliverDixon The 20 limit is the number of separate subscription items, not the quantity.

Answer (score 3):

Each subscription would have its own invoice and charge on Stripe's end for each new billing cycle and there is no way to bundle all of those into one without some custom development.

If you want to group all subscriptions on a customer into one charge, the best solution would be to use [Invoice Items](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/invoices#adding-invoice-items). You'd create a $0 monthly plan for all of your customers and then, each month, when you get the `invoice.created` event indicating that a new invoice has been created you'd create one [invoice item](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem) for each "subscription" you want to charge your customer for. Stripe would then charge the total amount at once for that invoice automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can add multiple plans to an existing subscription now. Below is the example:

```
sub = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve('sub_Aj4Wy1gzA5xyz')
sub.items = [{plan: "UserTestPlan"}, {plan: "UserTestPlan2"}]
sub.save
```

Comment: With using this 1.57.1 or greater version of stripe it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Stripe is limited in this area, IMHO.

While there are answers here to add multiple items to an invoice, it is limited to 20 and I don't think you can give them different names per item (I could be wrong on the last bit).  If you use multiple subscriptions per customer, then they are all on separate invoices.

We wanted to use Stripe to consolidate multiple clients' billing to our channel partner.  So the partner got one invoice and a line item for each client which clearly states the client's name etc.

Our conclusion... don't use Stripe for this if you have an unbounded number of items for the invoice each with its own item description

Answer (score -1):

According to the docs you can add a quantity to the Subscription that will charge you multiples of the Plan amount but on the same invoice:

```
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2"

Stripe::Subscription.create(
  :customer => "cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a",
  :plan => "pro-monthly",
  :quantity => 5,
)
```

There's a full page of docs about it [here](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quantities)

Comment: This doesn't help at all for subscribing to different plans, just multiple instances of the same plan. Thanks tho.

Comment: Ah apologies, I misunderstood the question. As far as I know there is no out of the box solution to what you're asking, but koopajah's solution looks interesting though. Best of luck!